# react-markdown shows div instead of element tag when using custom component

Tags: remarkjs, react-markdown

I'm trying to write a custom plugin for underline support ( with `~the underlined text~` syntax ) in react-markdown ( remark ) and the problem is the result uses *div* tag instead of *ins*.

here is the plugin:

```
const UNDERLINE_REGEX = /~(.*)~/g;

const extractPosition = (string, start, end) => {
    const startLine = string.slice(0, start).split("\n");
    const endLine = string.slice(0, end).split("\n");

    return {
        start: {
            line: startLine.length,
            column: startLine[startLine.length - 1].length + 1,
        },
        end: {
            line: endLine.length,
            column: endLine[endLine.length - 1].length + 1,
        },
    };
};

const extractText = (string, start, end) => ({
    type: "text",
    value: string.slice(start, end),
    position: extractPosition(string, start, end),
});

const underlinePlugin = () => {
    function transformer(tree) {
        console.log(tree);
        visit(tree, "text", (node, position, parent) => {
            const definition = [];
            let lastIndex = 0;

            const matches = node.value.matchAll(UNDERLINE_REGEX);

            for (const match of matches) {
                const value = match[1];
                const type = "underline";
                const tagName = "ins";

                if (match.index !== lastIndex) {
                    definition.push(
                        extractText(node.value, lastIndex, match.index)
                    );
                }

                definition.push({
                    type,
                    tagName,
                    children: [
                        extractText(
                            node.value,
                            match.index + 1, // 1 is start ~
                            match.index + value.length + 1 // 1 is start ~
                        ),
                    ],
                    position: extractPosition(
                        node.value,
                        match.index,
                        match.index + value.length + 2 // 2 is start and end ~
                    ),
                });

                lastIndex = match.index + value.length + 2; // 2 is start and end ~
            }

            if (lastIndex !== node.value.length) {
                const text = extractText(
                    node.value,
                    lastIndex,
                    node.value.length
                );
                definition.push(text);
            }

            const last = parent.children.slice(position + 1);
            parent.children = parent.children.slice(0, position);
            parent.children = parent.children.concat(definition);
            parent.children = parent.children.concat(last);
        });
    }

    return transformer;
};
```

Here is the Markdown usage:

```
<ReactMarkdown
        remarkPlugins={[plugin]}
        components={{
            ins: ({ value }) => <ins>{value}</ins>,
            underline: ({ value }) => <ins>{value}</ins>,
        }}>
        ~Hello~, **world**!
    </ReactMarkdown>
```

And here is the result

[image]

I used `type: 'underline'`, `type: 'ins'`, `tagName: 'underline'`, `'tagName: 'ins'`, but none of them works. I don't know what am I doing wrong here.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The [remark markdown processor](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark#) supports the [CommonMark specification](https://commonmark.org) which does not include support for `ins` or `del` tags. The [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown#react-markdown) component is, presumably, subject to [the CommonMark limitation (Why no underline?)](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/why-no-underline/3130).